# generating stubs from wsdl using axis 2 for client

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I am a new bie to the world of webservices , I have to develop the client side code that is the java code,I have been provided a wsdl which I can see by opening that wsdl in the browser , As i have access to wsdl , I am using Axis 2 , I have to use wsdl2java tool, which is available in axis2 distribution to generate the stubs.. Using those stub I need to write my client, so could you please share any url or example in which generating stubs from wsdl is shown using axis 2 as ultimately I have to generate client from wsdl

Comment: you have asked a same question yesterday, do you have generated client code now? If not, follow these steps(assuming you are using eclipse): 1:create a new run configuration, and search `WSDL2JAVA*` class, and put your wsdl address in `arguments` input, then run it. 2: after that you will get the generated client code, you can just use them just like normal java code.

Comment: well could you please share any url in which screenshots with an example is shown, that will be a great help. Although I get the following url http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html#createclients may help you. There you get the client java class as well.

Comment: I find this url to be more useful http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf